# Apache beam TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str [while running 'WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I'm trying to collect data from a MSSQL database and write it in Google Cloud Storage using Apache Beam.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType
import pyarrow

@LogicalType.register_logical_type
class db_str(LogicalType):
    @classmethod
    def urn(cls):
        return "beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1"

    @classmethod
    def language_type(cls):
        return str

    def to_language_type(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_representation_type(self, value):
        return str(value)


schema = pyarrow.schema([
    ('CurrencyID', pyarrow.string()),
    ('Currency', pyarrow.string())
    ])


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  ip1 = (p
  |ReadFromJdbc(
    table_name='xxx.xxx',
    driver_class_name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
    jdbc_url='jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433',
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx',
    classpath=['com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.2.jre8'],
    connection_properties = ';database=xxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;')
  |beam.io.WriteToParquet('gs://landingstorage/',schema=schema)
  )
```

I'm able to extract the table data and write a simple csv or txt document, but I cannot seem to get it into a parquet format.

It fails with this :
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str [while running 'WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']

Im running this from a google cloud shell.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually [ReadFromJdbc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.43.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html) native `Beam` IO returns a `PCollection` of `Tuple`.

The [WriteToParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.43.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html) native `Beam` IO is based on a `PCollection` of `Dict`.

To work correctly, your pipeline needs to transform the `PCollection` of `Tuple` provided by `ReadFromJdbc` to a `PCollection` of `Dict` before to call `WriteToParquet` IO, example :

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType
import pyarrow

@LogicalType.register_logical_type
class db_str(LogicalType):
    @classmethod
    def urn(cls):
        return "beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1"

    @classmethod
    def language_type(cls):
        return str

    def to_language_type(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_representation_type(self, value):
        return str(value)


schema = pyarrow.schema([
    ('CurrencyID', pyarrow.string()),
    ('Currency', pyarrow.string())
    ])

# Adapt to your case, with this coder you can get the result as Tuple instead of Beam schema.
CurrencyRow = typing.NamedTuple('CurrencyRow',
                               [('CurrencyID', string), ('Currency', string)])
coders.registry.register_coder(CurrencyRow, coders.RowCoder)

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  ip1 = (p
  |ReadFromJdbc(
    table_name='xxx.xxx',
    driver_class_name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
    jdbc_url='jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433',
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx',
    classpath=['com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.2.jre8'],
    connection_properties = ';database=xxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;')
  | "Tuple to Dict for Parquet" >> beam.Map(tuple_to_dict)
  | beam.io.WriteToParquet('gs://landingstorage/',schema=schema)
  )

def tuple_to_dict(tuple) -> Dict:
   return dict((y, x) for x, y in tuple)
```

Comment: Wait, I need to define every separate data field in the data dictionary?

Comment: I edited my answer with a dynamic approach to transform the Tuple to a Dict.

Comment: Getting the same error when running it like this :

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str [while running 'WriteToParquet/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']

Comment: Can you give me the exact type inside the PCollection after the call to `ReadFromJdbc` please ? With this I could test more easily your code.

Comment: I mean the source columns in the table are both varchar. I don't know if that's what you mean?

Comment: When I print out the data with beam.Map(print) I get this:
BeamSchema_67aaf3bf_1db6_4b20_bc69_639aad9ea72b(CurrencyID='EUR', Currency='Euro')
BeamSchema_67aaf3bf_1db6_4b20_bc69_639aad9ea72b(CurrencyID='SEK', Currency='Swedish Krona')
BeamSchema_67aaf3bf_1db6_4b20_bc69_639aad9ea72b(CurrencyID='GBP', Currency='British Pound')
BeamSchema_67aaf3bf_1db6_4b20_bc69_639aad9ea72b(CurrencyID='PLN', Currency='Polish Zloty')
36227896987d8723a0d9f51637349db7b77c460d98ad091c218658ad7f756d61

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how having the result as Tuple instead of Beam schema. Then the map from Tuple to Dict should work.

Comment: I've added the library "typing" necessary for running this. I guess thats is the library used in CurrencyRow and touple_to_dict(tuple) -> Dict; Also I changed the data format in the Currency row from string to str(as it bypassed the error I was getting)

But im still getting : TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: And if we defined the function tuple_to_dict, shouldn't the function go before the actual pipeline?